# Use deploy key in GitHub Actions to install dependency from private repo

Tags: ssh, github-actions, deploy-keys

Dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-repo": "git+ssh://github.com/org-name/my-repo.git"
  },
```

GitHub Actions:

```
name: Test
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'
          scope: '@org-name'
      - uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.4.1
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_KEY }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn
      - name: Test
        run: yarn test
```

The DEPLOY_KEY in the GitHub Actions secrets is the private key and I've added the corresponding public key as a deploy key in the dependency repo.

I generated the key with `ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 4096 -C "ssh://github.com/org-name/my-repo.git" -f ./deploykey -q -N ""`

Here's the failure I see in the GitHub Actions output:

```
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://github.com/org-name/my-repo.git
Directory: /home/runner/work/auth-package/auth-package
Output:
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.4' to the list of known hosts.
runner@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Really losing my mind on this one!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If I'm getting it right but to access to a different repo you need an access token. Therefore you need a Github Application with a private key secret. https://github.com/settings/apps

You need those three env variables in your workflow:

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: get secrets
    env:
      PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
      APP_ID: ${{ secrets.APP_ID }}
      INSTALLATION_ID: ${{ secrets.INSTALLATION_ID }}
```

Then create your JWT (check your JWT here: https://jwt.io/) to create the access token via REST API

```
run: |
      PEM=$PRIVATE_KEY
      GITHUB_APP_ID=$APP_ID
      NOW=$( date +%s )
      IAT="${NOW}"
      EXP=$((${NOW} + 600))
      HEADER_RAW='{"alg":"RS256"}'
      HEADER=$( echo -n "${HEADER_RAW}" | openssl base64 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '\n' )
      PAYLOAD_RAW='{"iat":'"${IAT}"',"exp":'"${EXP}"',"iss":'"${GITHUB_APP_ID}"'}'
      PAYLOAD=$( echo -n "${PAYLOAD_RAW}" | openssl base64 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '\n' )
      HEADER_PAYLOAD="${HEADER}"."${PAYLOAD}"
      SIGNATURE=$( openssl dgst -sha256 -sign <(echo -n "${PEM}") <(echo -n "${HEADER_PAYLOAD}") | openssl base64 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '\n' )
      JWT="${HEADER_PAYLOAD}"."${SIGNATURE}"
```

Then start your API CALL:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -sS -X POST \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer "$JWT"" \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
      https://github.com/api/v3/app/installations/"$INSTALLATION_ID"/access_tokens | grep -o '"token": "[^"]*' | grep -o '[^"]*$')
```

Then start with your Git Clone command:

```
git clone https://x-access-token:"$ACCESS_TOKEN"@github.com/../repo.git
      cd repo
      git config --global user.email "<email>"
      git config --global user.name "<name>"
      git branch upload
      git checkout upload
      git commit -m "update"
      git push --set-upstream origin upload
```

Then you can clone other repos in your current one for example. Be aware to grant the app access to the repos.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. However, I'm not using GitHub apps. I'm attempting to deploy a GitHub Package using GitHub Actions. My package has a dependency hosted in a private repo.